# how to find the game engine of an app in play store

Tags: android, google-play

I would like to know if there is a way to find which game engine a game uses, **especially** games that are on  **play store**

Also I want to know if decompiling the app will help?

if there is another way to get the engine without going through decompiling it would be great to know it

Comment: Though you could still decompile the apk and take a look. There might be some artefacts left over that give you a clue which engine was used. But this will differ from apk to apk and is not a guaranty that you will get a result

Comment: Also, why do you as a game developer even care? Just because someone picked a specific engine for their project doesn't mean that you should pick the same engine. Even if your project is very similar: The right engine for someone else is not necessarily the right engine for you.

Comment: @Zibelas that's what i thought also any doc that may help

Comment: @Philipp out of topic!

Comment: I am afraid *you* are the one being off-topic here. Please check [the help center article about what questions you can ask about here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You might notice that one of the questions you should **not** ask here is "what technology some particular game used". Please check [this meta-discussion about why we consider this off-topic](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/626/is-how-was-entire-game-x-made-off-topic/).

Comment: Voting to close as per [this](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2850/do-we-want-to-lower-the-amount-votes-to-close-reopen-a-question#comment6978_2850).

Comment: Please note that nothing in the question currently demonstrates that you need help in developing a game, which is the purpose of this site.

Comment: let it be closed I did my best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short version... No. There's nothing listed on the store that would tell you that (unless the dev includes it in the description).

Most marketplaces don't attempt to identify the technologies used (unless they come from the same source) and ultimately, the only technical requirement they're interested in is whether it will run on the target platform.

Also... It's worth noting that many games don't use a standard engine and are just coded directly (as mentioned in the comments this often results in the development of custom in-house engines that are used/evolved across multiple games).

Comment: Or use an in-house engine if the developer is big enough

Answer (score 0):

You find the developer's contact information and ask them. Maybe they'll have time and be kind enough to answer.

---

However, as it's been mentioned in the comments, having the infromation is most likely irrelevant.

If a wood sculptor is very proficient with a chainsaw, but you're an ace with an angle grinder, you'll probably end up creating better looking wood statues using angle grinder than if you clumsily used a chainsaw. Similarly, it's not because you know they have used engine X that you'll know how to use engine X to achieve similar results.

An engine is just a tool to an end. Use the tool you're the most comfortable with to get to that end.

That being said, even if you know they used X to get result Y in game Z, if you end up with result Y too, chances are that you'll be accused of copying Z in the playstore comments for your game.

Comment: your answer is off topic too that wasn't my intention if I'm looking to know what engin X game uses doesn't mean what you think it is. so you guys answer another question

Comment: My answer answers your question. If you don't need the addendum, that's fine. Keep in mind that other visitors may find this question for different motivations and heed the warning.

Comment: it's there to serve but you guys are both off topic, take it or leave it